# Adding variable javascript to a link for rotating images

Tags: javascript, html

I have 4 different images. These images rotate. On each image I need to insert a window.open option.  I thought perhaps locating it by id and changing the onclick would work.  Just links to the page I'm on. Below is what I have attempted.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
          function displayNextImage() {
              x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
              //document.getElementById("mylink").href=links[x];
              document.getElementById("mylink").onclick=links[x];

          }

          function displayPreviousImage() {
              x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

          function startTimer() {
              setInterval(displayNextImage, 5000);
          }

          var images = [], x = -1;
          images[0] = "/img/bakedline.png";
          images[1] = "/img/cornchipline.png";
          images[2] = "/img/friedline.png";
          images[3] = "/img/tortillaline.png";

          var links = new Array();
          links[0] = "window.open('/foodprocessor/cornchipline', 'my_new_window','toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=yes, width=625, height=400');";
          links[1] = "/foodprocessor/cornchipline";
          links[2] = "/foodprocessor/friedline";
          links[3] = "/foodprocessor/tortillachipline";


      </script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="imgs">
                            <a href="" id="mylink" onclick=""  ><img id="img" src="/img/bakedline.png"  /></a>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a function to the `onclick` property of the element not just the url you want to open. Something like this;

```
document.getElementById("mylink").onclick=function() { window.open(links[x]); };
```

See [GlobalEventHandlers.onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick)

Answer (score 0):

in your window open you are opening a folder

```
links[0] = "window.open('/foodprocessor/cornchipline' blah blah
```

try

```
links[0] = "window.open('/foodprocessor/cornchipline/index.php'
```

or what ever the file is called